# List AWS Quicksight dashboards per namespace

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-quicksight, aws-api-gateway

We have a demo Quicksight implementation using API Gateway and Lambda to provide embedded dashboards.
We now want to use namespaces within Quicksight to create a multi-tenant environment however the `ListDashboards` API endpoint does not accept a parameter identifying the namespace we want to query.

How do you query which dashboards are available for a particular namespace?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have namespaces set up but I see that a Quicksight User's ARN contains a **NameSpace** level such as the ones I have **highlighted** below [from the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/namespaces.html):

> "QuickSight considers these two entities to be different persons:
>
> - arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:111122223333:user/**namespace-123**/username123
> - arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:111122223333:user/**namespace-456**/username123"

And `describe-dashboard-permissions` lists all User ARNs so you will have to `list-dashboards`, iterate over this list with `describe-dashboard-permissions` and parse User ARNs for the matching list of namespaces. We use a variety of such iterative scripts for similar purposes because there aren't better pure API solutions (yet).

[This source](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=0fNNEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA204&lpg=PA204&dq=Quicksight%20IdentityStore%20by%20namespace) seems to show that namespaces don't appear in dashboard ARNs, and also that you have to use the CLI to share dashboards across namespaces as well. Cheers.